# CentOs 7 Python Issue “-bash: python: command not found”

Tags: centos, python, path, python3

I asked this at stackoverflow, but just realized it might be best here. If I need to delete it over there or should not have posted here, please let me know. I am still new to this site. Thanks in advance!

I'm using centos 7 and was trying to install python 3.4 alongside python 2.6 (2.7?) the default install. I was attempting to change my bashrc file with an alias to make python 3.4 the default from the shell. It did not work, and I commented out the script, resourced bashrc, and now the system acts as if it can no longer find python, default or otherwise.

Just typing "python" returns:

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

`which python` gives:

```
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/home/myusername/bin)
```

However there is a python install in both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.

`alternatives --list | grep -i python` yields:

```
    python  auto  /usr/bin/python3.4
```

`-v python` returns nothing.

`type -a python` gives:

```
 -bash: type: python: not found
```

`declare -p PATH` outputs

```
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/myusername/.local/‌​bin:/home/myusername/bin"
```

I am not entirely sure where to go from here, and any help would be much appreciated.

I do seem to have `/usr/bin/python`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun 25 15:39 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

but:

`$ ls -l $(readlink -f /usr/bin/python)` gives:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/python3.4: No such file or directory
```

I do not know if this is relevant, but `/etc/alternatives/python` was pink looking in the terminal.

Edit 2:

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/` prints `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   101 Sep  4  2014 2to3-3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   241 Sep  4  2014 easy_install-3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    99 Sep  4  2014 idle3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   213 Sep  4  2014 pip3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    84 Sep  4  2014 pydoc3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 17544 Sep  4  2014 python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 17544 Sep  4  2014 python3.4m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3066 Sep  4  2014 python3.4m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   236 Sep  4  2014 pyvenv-3.4`

So perhaps a linking error still?

Edit 3:

This is the series of commands which I used to install python 3.

`yum install scl-utils
sudo yum install scl-utils
sudo wget https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python33/epel-7-x86_64/download/rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install rhscl-python33-*.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Please don't cross-post. If you think this is a better fit (and you're probably right), please delete your question from SO. Otherwise, both will end up being closed.

Comment: Thank you for informing me, the other post has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've lost your python installation. You have a link at `/usr/bin/python` which is pointing to `/etc/alternatives/python`. However, that itself is a link that is pointing to `/usr/bin/python3.4` a file which apparently doesn't exist:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/python3.4: No such file or directory
```

So, it looks like you simply haven't installed python3.4. I suggest you ask a new question, explaining exactly how you installed it.

Comment: I will try adding that link and reply back with how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Bash returned: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists`

So apparently this link already exists, or am I not understanding the message?

Comment: @Aerdowaith no, you're understanding it perfectly. That's odd. Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and `ls -l $(readlink -f /usr/bin/python)`.

Comment: Links and symbolic links are a concept I have yet to fully grasp, so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Aerdowaith OK, see updated answer. You don't have python3.4 installed.

Comment: Could it just not be installed in the correct place? I installed it via yum if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Aerdowaith yes, it could but we can't know unless you explain precisely what you did. Post a new question and give the details of how you installed it please.

Comment: I have created a new question which can be found [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213118/centos7-python-3-4-install-method) .

Answer (score -1):

You used scl. It's a software collections install of python 3.4. You need to refer to the scl docs on running it. It's not what you would expect.

[Enabling a Software Collection](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/Software_Collections_Guide/sect-Enabling_the_Software_Collection.html)

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, it would be better if the gist of the contents of that other site could be summarised in the answer.

Comment: :-) ["Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)