# CentOs7 Python 3.4 Install Method

Tags: centos, python, bashrc

This post relates to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212961/centos-7-python-issue-bash-python-command-not-found/212983?noredirect=1#comment361367_212983) question where I was asked to explain how I installed python3 on my system. I was attempting to install python3 on my system for development purposes. Something went wrong along the line, and now my system does not recognize either the default python install, or the python 3.4 install. Also apps like yum are also broken.

```
sudo apt-get install curl git-core gcc make zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev
sudo yum install scl-utils
sudo wget https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python33/epel-7-x86_64/download/rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install rhscl-python33-*.noarch.rpm
```

Also, the line I appended and later removed from my .bashrc file was

```
alias python='/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3'
```

In retrospect I imagine that it should have been "python3.4" but either way, I assumed potentially incorrectly that simply commenting this line out would remove its effect.

Edit:
Also if memory serves, the apt-get was irrelevant because I was trying to install it the wrong way, so I really should not have included it here.

Edit Added outputs from commands:

Just typing "python" returns:

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

`which python` gives:

```
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/home/myusername/bin)
```

However there is a python install in both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.

`alternatives --list | grep -i python` yields:

```
python  auto  /usr/bin/python3.4
```

`-v python` returns nothing.

`type -a python` gives:

```
-bash: type: python: not found
```

`declare -p PATH` outputs

```
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/myusername/.local/‌​bin:/home/myusername/bin"
```

I do seem to have `/usr/bin/python`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun 25 15:39 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

but:

`$ ls -l $(readlink -f /usr/bin/python)` gives:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/python3.4: No such file or directory
```

I do not know if this is relevant, but `/etc/alternatives/python` was pink looking in the terminal.

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/` prints `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   101 Sep  4  2014 2to3-3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   241 Sep  4  2014 easy_install-3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    99 Sep  4  2014 idle3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   213 Sep  4  2014 pip3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    84 Sep  4  2014 pydoc3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 17544 Sep  4  2014 python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 17544 Sep  4  2014 python3.4m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3066 Sep  4  2014 python3.4m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   236 Sep  4  2014 pyvenv-3.4
```

Also,

```
/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3
```

Returns:

```
/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.3m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the new question. However, each question needs to stand alone. Please add the relevant details here: i) what symptoms you have; ii) the output of the various commands I asked for before. Also, note that you installed python3.3, not 3.4. What happens if you run `/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/bin/python3.3`?

Comment: @terdon edits made. Is the above what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Your system is in an inconsistent state because you did not separate the concerns of Python 2.7 (/usr/bin/python on CentOS7) for system use, from Python 3.5 for alternative uses like programming/scripting. CentOS 7 depends on /usr/bin/python being python2.7, and the most important use-case is Yum package management.

On a clean CentOS 7 system you would install Python 3.5 from [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python35/) with:

```bash
sudo yum install -y centos-release-scl
sudo yum install -y rh-python35
```

To enable it, you would source its environment in your shell:

```bash
. /opt/rh/rh-python35/enable
```

Then rather use `python3` to run your scripts in a portable way. (Note: `/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/bin/python` is an unfortunate symlink.)

The enable run configuration also creates envrionment variables like the LD_LIBRARY_PATH that python3.5 needs to find the shared libraries.

To get out of the mess your system is in, I would start by removing the symbolic links to python that point to /etc/alternatives from /usr/bin.

Ensure that /usr/bin/python2.7 is an ELF LSB executable.
Recreate the required symlinks:
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python

Once these work you should be able to use Yum again.